# viewForHeaderInSection not displaying label in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am looking to change the background colour and text colour of the uitableview sections using viewForHeaderInSection like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let sectionHeader = UIView()
    let sectionText = UILabel()

    sectionHeader.backgroundColor = .blue

    sectionText.textColor = .red
    sectionText.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
    sectionText.text = painkillersArray[section]["label"] as? String

    sectionHeader.addSubview(sectionText)

    return sectionHeader
}
```

The background is working but the text is not appearing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to set frames or use constraints. Better yet, do headers properly using `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and properly register and dequeue the header views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to give frame to both the view and label and also you have to provide heightForHeaderInSection:-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            let sectionHeader = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))

            let sectionText = UILabel()
            sectionText.frame = CGRect.init(x: 5, y: 5, width: sectionHeader.frame.width-10, height: sectionHeader.frame.height-10)
            sectionText.text = "Custom Text"
            sectionText.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold) // my custom font
            sectionText.textColor = .red // my custom colour

            sectionHeader.addSubview(sectionText)

            return sectionHeader
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 60 // my custom height
        }
```

Comment: This may work but you really should register and use a reusable header footer using `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. The above solution will be a problem on the iPhone X family of iPhones in landscape orientation.

Comment: Not wrapping to newline

Answer (score 0):

===
EDIT: I removed the first code I wrote, which didn't handle autolayout correctly. Morevoer, as @rmaddy pointed out in the comment below, it would be better if you use the provided `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` as is.

Register

```
tableView.register(UITableViewHeaderFooterView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "header")
```

in `viewDidLoad` and do

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                          viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "header")
    header?.textLabel?.text = "foo"
    return header
}
```

`header?.textLabel?.textColor = .red` won't work in the above method, so put customization code in

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                          viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "header")
    header?.textLabel?.text = "foo"
    return header
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
      header.textLabel?.textColor = .red
      header.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .blue
    }
  }
```

===

To use autolayout constraints with more complex headers, provide a custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass:

```swift
class CustomTableViewHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
  func commonInit() {
    let sectionHeader = UIView()
    let sectionText = UILabel()

    sectionHeader.backgroundColor = .blue

    sectionText.textColor = .red
    sectionText.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
    sectionText.text = "foo"

    sectionHeader.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sectionText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    sectionHeader.addSubview(sectionText)
    addSubview(sectionHeader)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      sectionHeader.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
      sectionHeader.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
      sectionHeader.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
      sectionHeader.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),

      sectionText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sectionHeader.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
      sectionText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sectionHeader.trailingAnchor),
      sectionText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sectionHeader.topAnchor, constant: 8),
      sectionText.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sectionHeader.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
    ])
  }

  override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    commonInit()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
  }
}
```

and register it in `viewDidLoad()`:

```swift
  func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    tableView.register(CustomTableViewHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "header")
    ...
  }
```

Then simply `dequeReusableHeaderFooterView`:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                          viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "header")
  }
```

Implement `heightForHeaderInSection` and `estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection` similarly.

Comment: Most of this isn't needed. `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` already has `titleLabel` and you don't need the extra view just to set the background. Just use the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` as-is. No need for the subclass.

Comment: *"Unfortunately, the above won't work if you need more than one section headers"* - It does work with multiple sections. But using `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` is better.

Comment: @rmaddy I just found out that the first code I wrote originally didn't handle autolayout correctly. Is there a way to correctly setup layout constraints to the "cell itself", when not registering `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` like the OP? `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` seems to put all the views in the upper-left corner of the safe area.

Comment: I am getting `NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: ...... (loaded)' with name 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView''`.